# Cant pause and resume nstimer in another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

Have myTimer defined in class One

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *myTimer;

 @synthesize myTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.6
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(updateView:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];

[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)updateView:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
if  (index < [textArray count])
{

   self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];
   self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
   index++;
}else{

    index = 0;

}
```

I want to pause and resume myTimer in mainviewcontroller class.

In mainviewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassOne *oneclass;
```

and in mainviewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize oneclass;
```

then via UIButton in mainviewcontroller pausing and resuming myTimer

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [audioPlayer pause];

    [myTimer invalidate];


}else{

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiostop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [audioPlayer play];

    [myTimer fire];

    if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:06.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO; } } }
```

But getting semantic issue and ARC Semantic issue error

**unknown receiver myTimer did you mean NSTimer. No known class method for selector invalidate and fire**

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you want to access any object created/"owned" by class One from class Two (or even another instance of class One), you must somehow obtain a pointer to the instance of class One that "owns" the object and access the object via that pointer.

Comment: FWIW, using names like "classOne" and "oneClass" and then naming your objects "one" or "oneClass" are generally very confusing. Try using more descriptive names and you will find that it makes life much easier and helps you diagnose problem areas. It looks like the class 'One' is actually a view controller, so it probably should be named something like 'timerPopupViewController'. Then, in your mainViewController you can create an object called 'timerPopup' that clearly tells you what it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Is myTimer set as a property of `ClassOne`?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

and

```
@synthesize myTimer;
```

Then you can call `[oneClass.myTimer invalidate];` and `[oneClass.myTimer fire];` in your mainviewcontroller.

Comment: myTimer is set as property in class named One. class name is just one not classone

Comment: so if i define @property (nonatomic, strong) ClassOne *oneclass; in mainviewcontroller is right or wrong

Comment: It's right, as far as I can tell. In that case, you can then call `[self.oneclass.myTimer invalidate];` and `[self.oneclass.myTimer fire]`.

Comment: if i define class like this@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassOne *oneclass;
it gives error unknown type name Classone

Comment: if i add code in this manner then gets error  [oneclass.myTimer invalidate]; member reference base type is not a structure or union

Comment: you need to import the header file from ClassOne into the mainViewController header file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating the timer object in the viewDidLoad method call. Make sure the view is actually loaded before you try to manipulate the timer property or the results will not be pleasant. Also, like @Anoop Vaidya said, you need to make sure you initialize a class One object before attempting to access its properties. A good way to do this is to modify your mainViewController code in the following way:

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
   //This code assumes there is an ivar in mainViewController called aClassOneObject
   if([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
     [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [audioPlayer pause];

     if (aClassOneObject)
       [[aClassOneObject myTimer] invalidate];
     else
       //Log error that the aClassOneObject was nil

   } else {
     [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiostop.png"] 
             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [audioPlayer play];

     if (aClassOneObject)
       [[aClassOneObject myTimer] fire];
     else
       //Log error that the aClassOneObject was nil

     if(isFirstTime == YES) {
       self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:06.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:NO];
       isFirstTime  = NO;
     }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling timer from other class, you need to call by creating an object of first class.

Or you can send a notification to first class from second class, that notification will be observed and then your required method will be called.